# Getting image data back from jQuery ajax request and displaying it in img tag

Tags: jquery, ajax, png

I'm using the dezgo api and whenever I get a response, I want to display it in an image tag.  This is my code:

```
 const settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://dezgo.p.rapidapi.com/text2image",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": "#####################",
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "dezgo.p.rapidapi.com"
    },
    "data": {
        "steps": "10",
        "guidance": "-20",
        "width": "512",
        "prompt": "an insect",
        "height": "512"
    }
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    
    console.log(response);

    var img = $('<img id="dynamic">');
    img.attr('src', "data:image/png;base64," + response);
    img.appendTo('#imgcontainer');

});
```

but I just wind up with an img like this:

<img id="dynamic" src="data:image/p�PNG

�
���
IHDR�������������{�C�����IDATx�<��dK�߉������g���7�2Y$�"�d��Z���ѣ�I��B� B�[
���"�*o��F����`fk������p"����{o���~���������Q-�si�^$Q�5����_���@"�__������v������Vۛ��%  ��<�HÐ�8���o���y�[�<=����7�˺�U���
�xwwLi����w_}�

It seems like it isn't encoding the data.

EDIT:  I modified this using IT goldman's suggestion

```
// var response = fake_api_result();
var prefix = 'data:image/png;base64,'
// document.querySelector("#img").src = prefix + btoa(response)



function fake_api_result(data) {
    var base64 = data;
    return atob(base64)
}

function encodeAndDisplayResult(data){

    var unencoded = fake_api_result(data);
    var encoded = btoa(unencoded);
    var img = $('<img id="dynamic">');
    img.attr('src', prefix + encoded);
    img.appendTo('#imgcontainer');

}


const settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://dezgo.p.rapidapi.com/text2image",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": "####################",
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "dezgo.p.rapidapi.com"
    },
    "data": {
        "steps": "10",
        "guidance": "-20",
        "width": "512",
        "prompt": "an insect",
        "height": "512"
    }
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {

    console.log(response);

    encodeAndDisplayResult(response);


});
```

Now it says: "Uncaught DOMException: String contains an invalid character"

Comment: I've now been through several SO threads.  @dqhendricks I'm trying to do the reverse of what the OP in your linked post wants to do.  I still don't know whether the returned response is binary or base64.  I've tried to convert it 64>binary and binary>64  Nothing works.  If I go to the browser console>Network>Response I can see the image preview.  At this point I'd be happy if I could just pull the full image out of the browser memory.  Any advice on that?

Comment: I see. In your second example, you seem to be first decoding the data from base64 `atob()`, then re-encoding it as base64 `btoa()`. do you know whether the api image is base64 or not? does dezgo API not tell you how to do exactly what you are trying to do in their docs?

Comment: @dqhendricks There is a tutorial and an about tab.  Both are blank.  There is a discussion section where I've also asked my question.  Hopefully they can give me the info I need.  I've even tried taking that response, saving it to a text file and changing the extension from .txt to .png but the image viewer will not read it.

Comment: I tried using:  

function hexToBase64(str) {
    return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, str.replace(/\r|\n/g, "").replace(/([\da-fA-F]{2}) ?/g, "0x$1 ").replace(/ +$/, "").split(" ")));
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
 console.log('done');
 var img = $('<img id="dynamic">');
    img.attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + hexToBase64(response));
    img.appendTo('#imgcontainer');
});

comes back as:

"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA........

Comment: I tried using what was suggested here: https://attacomsian.com/blog/javascript-base64-encode-decode

No errors.  My img src now starts with "77+9..." which looks right but no image is displayed

Comment: well you still seem to have both decoding from base64 and then re-encoding to base 64 in your second example code above. you would either need one, or the other, or neither. never both. do you see what i am talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you don't need fake_api_result function. You may try this

```
var prefix = 'data:image/png;base64,'

function encodeAndDisplayResult(data){
    var encoded = btoa(data);
    var img = $('<img id="dynamic">');
    img.attr('src', prefix + encoded);
    img.appendTo('#imgcontainer');

}


const settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://dezgo.p.rapidapi.com/text2image",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": "####################",
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "dezgo.p.rapidapi.com"
    },
    "data": {
        "steps": "10",
        "guidance": "-20",
        "width": "512",
        "prompt": "an insect",
        "height": "512"
    }
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {

    console.log(response);

    encodeAndDisplayResult(response);


});
```

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: String contains an invalid character

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their help.  I got the information I needed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a raw PNG data. That's a binary I think so you need to convert it to base64 and use it directly as `src` of image. Alternatively, maybe some kind of reader idk. Lets try

```js
var response = fake_api_result();
var prefix = 'data:image/png;base64,'
document.querySelector("#img").src = prefix + btoa(response)



function fake_api_result() {
  var base64 = `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`
  return atob(base64)
}
```

```html
<img id="img">
```

In your case, your code should look like and hopefully work:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    
    var base64 = btoa(response)

    var img = $('<img id="dynamic">');
    img.attr('src', "data:image/png;base64," + base64);
    img.appendTo('#imgcontainer');

});
```

Comment: I added your code to mine and modified it a little.  It's now telling me "Uncaught DOMException: String contains an invalid character"